# Rails not detecting jquery

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My application.js:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree .
```

My application.html.erb:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>MyApp</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>

<%= yield %>

</body>
</html>
```

I've added `delete_alert.js` into `app/assets/javascripts` and `jquery.js` into `vendor/assets/javascripts`. In `delete_alert.js` I call $ but console gives `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined`.

As I understand, jquery should be in application.js minified version as I require it in application.js. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you add `jquery-rails` to your Gemfile?

Comment: what does your js console say?

Comment: try installing rails jquery turbolinks gem and add //= require jquery.turbolinks to application.js